# vista programdata command line access

Tags: delphi, windows-vista

I have an application  which stores data (original.dat ) to folder C:\ProgramData 
(I use SHGetFolderPath() with CSIDL of CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA. to access the folder)

It also need to call a command line execute file(myexecute.exe) with parameter
c:\program files\myname\appname\myexecute.exe original.dat outputfile.dat (outputfile.dat  will be in C:\ProgramData)
It worked on xp, but it reported error 'access denied' on vista.
It look like it is foreboded for creating the outputfile.dat in the folder.

Welcome any comment

Thanks

marc

Comment: If you want specific guidance, a snippet of code that generates the error would really help.  Also, what version of Delphi?

Comment: No need for code here, just need to stop writing to folders to which you don't have write access, as Ken says

Comment: Is there a folder in vista that has no problem about 'access denied' in any case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA is for all users, and is not writable for non-admin users because of UAC. It's writable for administrators during install, but shouldn't be used afterwards.

You should use CSIDL_APPDATA for the current user's data instead.

Comment: +1. [Some Microsoft guidelines for use of CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995853.aspx). I looked it up because it's not intuitive to me. The link says: `By default, this location is read-only for normal (non-admin, non-power) Users. If an application requires normal Users to have write access to an application specific subdirectory of CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, then the application must explicitly modify the security on that sub-directory during application setup.`.

Comment: CSIDL_APPDATA, same result, and I estimate most of vista compatible problem are related to this

Comment: I just wonder if I need to do something when installing my application(I use Inno Setup, maybe I need to do something in Inno scripts)

Comment: I do not hope to upgrade the UAC privilege to administrator. This is not the way I prefer.

Comment: @monsabre, just found that in InnoSetup scripts you can use {commonappdata} for referencing CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA